# As with the command: "echo '#!/bin/bash' |tee file", but with "echo '#!/bin/bash' | myscript file"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cat

What "... | tee file" does is take stdin (standard input) and divert it to two places:  stdout (standard output) and to a path/file named "file".  In effect it does this, as far as I can judge:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    var=(cat)       # same as var=(cat /dev/stdin)
    echo -e "$var"
    for file in "$@"
    do
      echo -e "$var" > "${file}"
    done
    exit 0
```

So I use the above code to create tee1 to see if I could emulate what tee does.  But my real intent is to write a modified version that appends to existing file(s) rather than redo them from scratch.  I call this one tee2:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  var=(cat)       # same as var=(cat /dev/stdin)
  echo -e "$var"
  for file in "$@"
  do
    echo -e "$var" >> "${file}"
  done
  exit 0
```

It makes sense to me, but not to bash.  Now an alternative approach is to do something like this:

```
  echo -e "$var"
  for file in "$@"
  do
    echo -e "$var"| tee tmpfile
    cat tmpfile  >> "${file}"
  done
  rm tmpfile
  exit 0
```

It also makes sense to me to do this:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  cp -rfp /dev/stdin tmpfile
  cat tmpfile
  for file in "$@"
  do
    cat tmpfile >> "${file}"
  done
  exit 0
```

Or this:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  cat /dev/stdin
  for file in "$@"
  do
    cat /dev/stdin  >> "${file}"
  done
  exit 0
```

Some online searches suggest that printf be used in place of echo -e for more consistency across platforms.  Other suggest that cat be used in place of read, though since stdin is a device, it should be able to be used in place of catm as in:

```
    > tmpfile
    IFS=\n
    while read line
   do
     echo $line >> tmpfile
     echo $line
   done < /dev/stdin
   unset IFS
```

Then the for loop follows.  But I can't get that to work. How can I do it with bash?

Comment: You're using array assignments `var=(cat)` instead of command substitution `var=$(cat)`.  This is certainly sending things in the wrong direction.  Of course, the 'real' `tee` reads and writes to files as the data is produced, rather than waiting until EOF on its standard input before writing to any of the outputs, but that's mostly a technicality.

Answer (score 4):

> But my real intent is to write a modified version that appends to existing file(s) rather than redo them from scratch.

The `tee` utility is specified to support an `-a` option, meaning "Append the output to the files." [[spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html)]

(And I'm not aware of any implementations of `tee` that deviate from the spec in this regard.)

---

**Edited to add:** If your question is really "what's wrong with all the different things I tried", then, that's probably too broad for a single Stack Overflow question. But here's a short list:

- `var=(cat)` means "Set the array variable `var` to contain a single element, namely, the string `cat`."

  - Note that this does not, in any way, involve the program `cat`.
  - You probably meant `var=$(cat)`, which means "Run the command `cat`, capturing its standard output. Discard any null bytes, and discard any trailing sequence of newlines. Save the result in the regular variable `var`."

    - Note that even this version is not useful for faithfully implementing `tee`, since `tee` does *not* discard null bytes and trailing newlines. Also, `tee` forwards input as it becomes available, whereas `var=$(cat)` has to wait until input has completed. (This is a problem if standard input is coming from the terminal — in which case the user would expect to see their input echoed back — or from a program that might be trying to communicate with the user — in which case you'd get a deadlock.)
- `echo -e "$var"` makes a point of processing escape sequences like `\t`. (That's what the `-e` means.) This is not what you want. In addition, it appends an extra newline, which isn't what you want if you've managed to set `$var` correctly. (If you *haven't* managed to set `$var` correctly, then this might help compensate for that, but it won't really fix the problem.)

  - To faithfully print the contents of `var`, you should write `printf %s "$var"`.
- I don't understand why you switched to the `| tee tmpfile` approach. It doesn't improve anything so far as I can tell, and it introduces the bug that now if you're copying to *n* files, then you will also write *n* copies to standard output. (You fixed that bug in later versions, though.)
- The versions where you write *directly* to a file, instead of saving to a variable first, are a massive improvement in terms of faithfully copying the contents of standard input. But they still have the problem of waiting until input is complete.
- The version where you `cat /dev/stdin` multiple times (once for each destination) won't work, because there's no "rewinding" of standard input. Once something is consumed, it's gone. (This makes sense when you consider that standard input is frequently passed around from program to program — your `cat`-s, for example, are inheriting it from your Bash script, and your Bash script may be inheriting it from the terminal. If some sort of automatic rewinding were to happen, how would it decide how far back to go?) (Note: if standard input is coming from a regular file, then it's possible to *explicitly* seek backward along it, and thereby "unconsume" already-consumed input. But that doesn't happen automatically, and anyway that's not possible when standard input is coming from a terminal, from a pipe, etc.)

Comment: thank you for the info!  Makes my life a bit easier. But having hot this far, I'm pushing ahead.  Handling stdin, stfout, and stderr, I can now proceed to write my own filters and utilities.  Like a "locate